# Converting a Single Linked List to a Double Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have here a single linked list for a  program that makes a collage.  This runs perfectly but I was wondering how to make it a double linked list.  I really have no idea what a double linked is though or how to create one. Any help would be appreciated...

There are 3 classes.

```
class LinearCollage
{
  private Picture myArray[];
  private class Node
  {
    Picture data;
    Node pNext;
  };

  private Node pFirst;
  private Node pLast;

  private int nPictures;  
  private Picture clipboard;
  public LinearCollage()
  {
    pFirst = null;
    pLast = null;
    nPictures = 0;

  }
  public void addPictureAtEnd(Picture aPictureReference)
  {
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.data = aPictureReference;
    temp.pNext = null;
    if( pLast == null )
    {
      pLast = temp;
      pFirst = temp;
    }
    else
    {
      pLast.pNext = temp;
      pLast = temp;
    }
    nPictures++;
  }
  public Picture makeCollage()
  {
    int collageHeight = 400;
    int collageWidth = 400;
    for( Node finger = pFirst; finger != null; finger = finger.pNext )
    {
      System.out.println("Process Picture " + finger.data);
    }
    Picture retval = new Picture(collageHeight,collageWidth);
    int i = 0;
    for( Node finger = pFirst; finger != null; finger = finger.pNext )
    {
      System.out.println("Process Picture " + finger.data);
      finger.data.compose(retval, 50*i, 50*i);
      i++;
    }
    return retval;
  }
  public void cutMiddle()
  {
    int cutIndex = nPictures-1;
    clipboard = myArray[cutIndex];
    for( int i = cutIndex; i < nPictures - 1; i++ )
    {
      myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
    }
    nPictures--;
  }
  public void cutEnd()
{
int cutIndex = nPictures;
clipboard = myArray[cutIndex];
for( int i = cutIndex; i<nPictures - 1; i++)
{
myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
}
nPictures--;
}
public void pasteEnd()
{
myArray[nPictures] = clipboard;
nPictures++;
}
  public boolean isFull()
  {
    return false;
  }
  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return nPictures == 0;
  }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
class LineCollageMaker
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    LinearCollage myCollage;
    Scanner uiInput = new Scanner(System.in);


    myCollage = new LinearCollage();

    FileChooser.pickMediaPath();
    boolean inputting = true;
    while( inputting ) 
    {
      System.out.println("Another picture? Type Y if so.");
      String answer = uiInput.next();
      if(answer.equals("Y"))
      {
        Picture pin = new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile());
        myCollage.addPictureAtEnd(pin);
      }
      else
      {
        inputting = false;
      }


    }
    Picture firstToShow = myCollage.makeCollage();
    firstToShow.show();
    //YOU Code the user inteface loop and dispatch to methods
    //of myCollage here..
    boolean done = false;
   while( !done )
    {
      System.out.println("MENU (CASE SENSITIVE!)");
      System.out.println("CM - cut middle and move it to the clipboard");
      System.out.println("PE - paste clipboard to end");
      System.out.println("CE - cut end and move it to clipboard");
      System.out.println("XX - stop running this program");
      String command = uiInput.next();
      if(command.equals("XX"))
        done = true;
      else if(command.equals("CM"))
      {
        if(myCollage.isEmpty())
        {
          System.out.println("Can't cut from an empty collage.");
        }
        else
        {
          myCollage.cutMiddle();
          myCollage.makeCollage().show();
        }
      }
      else if(command.equals("PE"))
      {
        if(myCollage.isFull())
        {
          System.out.println("Can't paste to an empty collage.");
        }
        else
        {
         myCollage.pasteEnd();
         myCollage.makeCollage().show();
        }
      }
        else if(command.equals("CE"))
      {
        if(myCollage.isEmpty())
        {
          System.out.println("Can't copy from an empty collage.");
        }
        else
        {
         myCollage.cutEnd();
         myCollage.makeCollage().show(); 
        }
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Unrecognized command. Try again.");
    }

  }
}



public class Node
{
  //le class variables
  private Picture myPic;
  private Node next;

  //le constructors  
  public Node(Picture heldPic)
  {
    myPic=heldPic;
    next=null;
  }

  public void setNext(Node nextOne)
  {
    this.next=nextOne;
  }
  public Node getNext()
  {
   return this.next; 
  }
  public Picture getPicture()
  {
   return this.myPic; 
  }


  //le methods
  public void drawFromMeOn(Picture bg)
  {
   Node current;
   int currentX=0, currentY=bg.getHeight()-1;

   current = this;
   while (current != null)
   {
    current.drawMeOn(bg,currentX, currentY);
    currentX = currentX + current.getPicture().getWidth();
    current=current.getNext();
   }
  }

 private void drawMeOn(Picture bg, int left, int bottom)
 {
  this.getPicture().blueScreen(bg, left, bottom-this.getPicture().getHeight());
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: If you have no idea what a doubly-linked list is, why do you want to convert this implementation to one?

Comment: Sorry about that. Wasn't aware of that rule.

Answer (score 3):

A doubly linked list is simply a linked list where every element has both next and prev mebers, pointing at the elements before and after it, not just the one after it in a single linked list.

so to convert your list to a doubly linked list, just change your node to be:

```
private class Node
  {
    Picture data;
    Node pNext;
    Node pPrev;
  };
```

and when iterating the list, on each new node add a reference to the previous node.

Comment: dont forget that the prev member of the first element is `null`, so it the next member of the last element :).

Comment: How would referencing a previous node on each new one? Also @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @methos when you create a new node, simply add the current top node as prev. pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

A doubly-linked list takes a singly-linked list one step further by also having a reference to the previous node, rather than just the next one.

I confess I am slightly confused by your code as it looks like you have a private class for Node and then another public class for it. To make this a doubly-linked list add another Node instance variable into your Node class which references the previous node, and then update this variable when you add in new nodes.

Comment: I also have same view that why two node classes are required here.One private class will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Single linked list to Double linked list via a concept called XOR based linked list. The beauty of XOR truth table makes suitable for this use case.

Check this out : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-linked-list-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-set-1/

Comment: Link to example C++ code for xorlist: https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/xorlist.cpp .

Answer (score 0):

To build off of previous answers, you will want to have a next and previous node within the internal Node class. You will then establish a paramaterized constructor within the node class to set everything (not really necessary if what you have works). One of the most important things when implementing a double linked list if you want to be able to remove an element, the Node.previous.next will need to be set to Node.next, and the Node.next.previous will need to be set to Node.previous. This is because the linked list now has two links now, so you will have to connect both forward and backward. Note that this is assuming that you keep the bare minimum of pointers at first and last. If you were to implement additional next and previous pointers, which would use some additional memory, you could also rephrase remove as setting next to current and current to previous, then setting previous, if it exists, to current's previous.Also, on your add and remove methods, you will have to ensure that you link the pLast.prev to it's new previous node in addition to linking the next of it. This is because you now have two links to look after instead of one.

Comment: I think your answer could be improved if you [edit] it and post some code illustrating what you describe.