# Convert singly linked list to a doubly linked list using java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I understand the concept of LinkedList, and single/doubly linked list. I, however don't understand how to implement it to my code?

I have to convert this singly list to a doubly linked list:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> extends MyAbstractList<E> {
  private Node<E> head, tail;

  /** Create a default list */
  public MyLinkedList() {
  }

  /** Create a list from an array of objects */
  public MyLinkedList(E[] objects) {
    super(objects);
  }

  /** Return the head element in the list */
  public E getFirst() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return head.element;
    }
  }

  /** Return the last element in the list */
  public E getLast() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return tail.element;
    }
  }

  /** Add an element to the beginning of the list */
  public void addFirst(E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e); // Create a new node
    newNode.next = head; // link the new node with the head
    head = newNode; // head points to the new node
    size++; // Increase list size

    if (tail == null) // the new node is the only node in list
      tail = head;
  }

  /** Add an element to the end of the list */
  public void addLast(E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e); // Create a new for element e

    if (tail == null) {
      head = tail = newNode; // The new node is the only node in list
    }
    else {
      tail.next = newNode; // Link the new with the last node
      tail = tail.next; // tail now points to the last node
    }

    size++; // Increase size
  }


  @Override /** Add a new element at the specified index 
   * in this list. The index of the head element is 0 */
  public void add(int index, E e) {
    if (index == 0) {
      addFirst(e);
    }
    else if (index >= size) {
      addLast(e);
    }
    else {
      Node<E> current = head;
      for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        current = current.next;
      }
      Node<E> temp = current.next;
      current.next = new Node<E>(e);
      (current.next).next = temp;
      size++;
    }
  }

  /** Remove the head node and
   *  return the object that is contained in the removed node. */
  public E removeFirst() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      Node<E> temp = head;
      head = head.next;
      size--;
      if (head == null) {
        tail = null;
      }
      return temp.element;
    }
  }

  /** Remove the last node and
   * return the object that is contained in the removed node. */
  public E removeLast() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (size == 1) {
      Node<E> temp = head;
      head = tail = null;
      size = 0;
      return temp.element;
    }
    else {
      Node<E> current = head;

      for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++) {
        current = current.next;
      }

      Node<E> temp = tail;
      tail = current;
      tail.next = null;
      size--;
      return temp.element;
    }
  }

  @Override /** Remove the element at the specified position in this 
   *  list. Return the element that was removed from the list. */
  public E remove(int index) {   
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (index == 0) {
      return removeFirst();
    }
    else if (index == size - 1) {
      return removeLast();
    }
    else {
      Node<E> previous = head;

      for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        previous = previous.next;
      }

      Node<E> current = previous.next;
      previous.next = current.next;
      size--;
      return current.element;
    }
  }

  @Override /** Override toString() to return elements in the list */
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

    Node<E> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      result.append(current.element);
      current = current.next;
      if (current != null) {
        result.append(", "); // Separate two elements with a comma
      }
      else {
        result.append("]"); // Insert the closing ] in the string
      }
    }

    return result.toString();
  }

  @Override /** Clear the list */
  public void clear() {
    size = 0;
    head = tail = null;
  }

  @Override /** Return true if this list contains the element e */
  public boolean contains(E e) {
    System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    return true;
  }

  @Override /** Return the element at the specified index */
  public E get(int index) {
    System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    return null;
  }

  @Override /** Return the index of the head matching element in 
   *  this list. Return -1 if no match. */
  public int indexOf(E e) {
    System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    return 0;
  }

  @Override /** Return the index of the last matching element in 
   *  this list. Return -1 if no match. */
  public int lastIndexOf(E e) {
    System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    return 0;
  }

  @Override /** Replace the element at the specified position 
   *  in this list with the specified element. */
  public E set(int index, E e) {
    System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    return null;
  }

  @Override /** Override iterator() defined in Iterable */
  public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new LinkedListIterator();
  }

  private void checkIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
        ("Index: " + index + ", Size: " + size);
  }

  private class LinkedListIterator 
      implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
    private Node<E> current = head; // Current index 

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return (current != null);
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
      E e = current.element;
      current = current.next;
      return e;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      System.out.println("Implementation left as an exercise");
    }
  }

  private static class Node<E> {
    E element;
    Node<E> next;

    public Node(E element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
  }
}
```

So I understand to add a previous pointer, I have to do this:

```
  private static class Node<E> {
    E element;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> previous;


    public Node(E element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
```

Now, I am confused - how do I actually implement the necessary methods for the doubly linked list? I am not asking for someone to do the entire assignment, but can someone show me an example of a worked out method?

I also couldn't understand, how does the program know I am referencing the previous element when I do `Node<E> previous`?

Comment: try the source of [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for reference. [LinkedList.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html)

Comment: take a look at this 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542154/converting-a-single-linked-list-to-a-double-linked-list

Answer (score 2):

> I also dont understand, just because I do "Node previous", how does the program know I am referencing the previous element?

The program *doesn't* know that you are referencing the previous element. You, the programmer, need to maintain (keep up-to-date and correct) that reference.

Answer (score 1):

Every node will also have a reference to the previous node as it has reference to the next node.
Change the data structure of Node to add an extra Node reference to previous node. So now when someone calls the `add(E e)` method you will add that element at the tail and set the previous reference of `e` ***(which will be the new tail node)*** to the older tail node (which was the tail before add was called).
So in this way you are managing two references to previous and next nodes.
Also add a new method to your double link list class `pervious()` and related ones.